# Connection this heating element with electrical plug?

Tags: heat, plug

that’s are the heating element that i want to know how to connect that with electrical plug

[link](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Silver-Tone-220V-2500W-Heating-Element-Resistance-Coil-Wire-6-Pcs/32248081793.html?spm=2114.30010308.3.2.Dt2Ib9&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_10%2Csearchweb201602_2_10017_10021_507_10022_10020_10009_401_10008_10018_10019_101%2Csearchweb201603_2&btsid=8c784dc4-6eb0-498c-b41b-b00aefe778e9)

Comment: Google "replace kiln element" for instructions- usually a crimp or screw connector. These are open elements and intended to sit in slots in firebrick or otherwise be supported.. and they must be electrically insulated for function and (especially) safety.

Answer (score 2):

Please. Find an electrician. Do not do this on the advice of strangers on the internet. You may kill yourself or somebody you care about. You may burn down your house or apartment. Don't do it.

Please.